# Create a template for thesis report with custom fonts

Tags: fontsize, document-classes

I want to write my thesis report using latex. I want to create a template for this so anybody in my class can use this easily. I these font sizes

- 11 [Chapter Body]
- 12
- 14
- 16 [Chapter Title]
- 18

What documentclass should I use? And can I get these font sizes?

Comment: You only need `book`, the normal one, actually. Then edit the chapter title or so. Please add a minimal working example, anyway

Comment: Welcome, you should start by reading an introduction to LaTeX. Your question hints that you do not understand the basic principles yet.